# React native: undefined UIManager in sketch canvas

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm learning React Native right now and trying to make use of [this react canvas component](https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas).

So, that's what I did:

```
react-native init MyProject
cd MyProject
react-native run-ios
```

I was able to see sample page in iOS simulator. Next I installed mentioned component:

```
npm install @terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas --save
```

And changed App.js file to use code from the example. However, now when I run code I see the following error:

undefined is not an object (evaluating _reactNative.UIManager.RNSketchCanvas.Constants)

I've tried to do `rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081); react-native run-ios` but it didn't help.

Any advice? At what point _reactNative.UIManager gets populated?

Comment: You forgot to link the dependencies `react-native link @terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas` which causes this error. If it still fails then you need to link manually

Comment: @PritishVaidya yep, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Same error here. I already did  react-native link @terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas  but nothing happened.